# PowerShell replace doesn't work in the last line in my script

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I use PSVersion 5.1.19041.1320.

I'm getting a security descriptor of Windows Service and truing to replace access rights in it (in this example with 'TEST') for a specific user (in the example for 'AU').

My general logic is:

1. Take a service's Security Descriptor
2. Extract a part between 'D:' and 'S:' (with regex '(?<=D:)(.*)(?=S:)')
3. Extract access rights for Authenticated Users (AU) (with regex '(([^()]*))'    the )
4. Replace access rights
5. Assemble 3. and 2. back to a new security descriptor

Example:

```
$user = 'AU'
[string]$newAccessRights = 'TEST'
$sddl = sc.exe sdshow wuauserv | Where-Object {$_}
$dacl = [RegEx]::Matches($sddl,'(?<=D:)(.*)(?=S:)') | ForEach-Object {$_.Value}
$dacl = $dacl -replace ([RegEx]::Matches($dacl,"(\([^()]*\))") | Where-Object {$_.Value.split(';')[-1] -eq "${user})"} | ForEach-Object {$_.Value.split(';')[2]}), $newAccessRights
$sddl -replace ([RegEx]::Matches($sddl,"(?<=D:)(.*)(?=S:\()") | ForEach-Object {$_.Value}), $dacl
```

my expectation is that Security Descriptor:

> D:(A;;**CCLCSWRPLORC**;;;AU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOSDRCWDWO;;;WD)

will be replaced with:

> D:(A;;**TEST**;;;AU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOSDRCWDWO;;;WD)

but it is not:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEwK1.png)

What am I doing wrong?
Why the only last replace doesn't work?

Comment: You're forgetting to escape the values you get back from `Regex.Matches`, change the last statement to `$sddl -replace ([regex]::Escape(([RegEx]::Matches($sddl,"(?<=D:)(.*)(?=S:\()") | ForEach-Object {$_.Value}))), $dacl` and it'll work (you should probably escape the user/principal argument in the dacl in the line above as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$sddl = $sddl -replace "(\((?:[^();]*;){2})\w+((?:;[^()]*)?;$user\))", "`$1$newAccessRights`$2"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/E1OjqV/2). *Details*:

- `(\((?:[^();]*;){2})` - Group 1 (`$1`): a `(` char, then two occurrences of any zero or more chars other than `(`, `)` and `;` followed with a `;` char
- `\w+` - one or more word chars (or, `[^;]*` matching zero or more chars other than a `;` char, it will work here, too)
- `((?:;[^()]*)?;$user\))` - Group 2 (`$2`): an optional sequence of a `;` and then any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then `;`, `$user` variable, and a `)` char.

**NOTE**: If `$user` has no special chars, no need to `Regex.Escape` it. Else, escape it, `[regex]::Escape($user)`. And if there is a `$` char in the `$newAccessRights` followed with a digit, you will need to escape it, too, `$newAccessRights.Replace('$', '$$')` (this can be done before using it in the replacement pattern).